# Tkinter escape binding not destroying

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to learn tkinter and the idea that I have requires it to be in fullscreen. Before making it fullscreen, however I wanted to make sure I could close the window using escape. So through other questions similar to this one on Stack Overflow I have been trying to get it to destroy the tkinter window when I hit escape. To me this seems like it should work but I am getting an exception when I hit escape:

```
    `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: destroy() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`
```

This is confusing for me because I don't think I am calling any arguments at all let alone 2. I have added a quit button which calls the `close` method I made and that works but using escape doesn't seem to. I have supplied my code for clarity. I know this is similar to a lot of questions on here but I have tried everything and nothing seems to be working for me. Thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        master.bind('<Escape>', master.destroy)

        self.init_window()
    def init_window(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        quitButton = Button(self, text="quit", command=self.close)
        quitButton.place(x=0, y=0)

    def close(self):
        self.master.destroy()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500')
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 6):

When  you bind a function to an event, tkinter will always pass an event object to that function. The `destroy` function takes no arguments, which means you can't bind directly to it. You need to bind to a function that will accept the event object as an argument.

Since you already have a function, you can give it an optional named argument so that you can continue to call your function without the argument, but it can also be used in a binding:

```
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        ...
        master.bind('<Escape>', self.close)

    def close(self, event=None):
        self.master.destroy()
```

You could also use an anonymous function:

```
master.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: master.destroy())
```

Comment: OH! I did not realize that an event object was being passed as well! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works.
I used it in a class for creating a full screen app in a `800x480` touch screen for pi:

```
class FullScreenApp(object):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800,480))
        master.bind('<Escape>', self.close)

    def close(self, event=None):
        self.master.destroy()
```